# A new method of newline. Is it a compiler specific feature or new language standard?

Tags: c

Today I played a tiny c compiler called 'TinyCC' and I found an interesting feature.

Usually if we are going to draw a tree, we shall using code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("    *\n");
    printf("   * *\n");
    printf("  *   *\n");
    printf(" *******\n");
    printf("    *\n");
    printf("   ***\n");
}
```

Or

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("\n\
    *\n\
   * *\n\
  *   *\n\
 *******\n\
    *\n\
   ***");
}
```

But I was surprised to find that this code works fine which would certainly report an error according to my experience:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("
    *
   * *
  *   *
 *******
    *
   ***
");
}
```

I thought it was c99's new feature but could not find it. Is it a compiler feature or what?

ps, I just tested in gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2. It reported errors as I expected. However it is not a c99 compiler, so I could not make a conclusion. I am looking for another c99 compiler.

Comment: Using strings like that have been in C since almost the beginning.

Comment: Don't you need backslashes to escape the newline?

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't in standard C, and no other compiler I know supports it.

Comment: I agree, not standard C. printf need "\" to go to a newline, otherwise won't compile (tested on llvm 7, errors as expected).

Answer (score 0):

You gave `printf` a string that already contains newline characters and so it will just print them.